# how to know if a button has been clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know if the button to draw points on this map ...

https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/083a0b48c2cc78c4a08d

is clicked.

I've tried to use this Javascript code ..

```
var editButton = document.getElementsByClassName('mapbox-gl-draw_ctrl-draw-btn mapbox-gl-draw_point'); // grab a reference to your element
editButton.onclick = function(){
        alert("Clicked!");
    }
```

... but nothing happens (no error ... ).

If I try to check for the editButton variable value in my Chrome console I can see that it's a HTMLCollection[1], so not empty ...

Suggestions / example / alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. You need to set the click handler for the actual element.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mapbox-gl-draw_ctrl-draw-btn mapbox-gl-draw_point');
var editButton = elements[0];
```